# How to redirect a user in flutter after verified their email?

Tags: flutter, email, firebase-authentication, email-verification, onpress

Hello I am new in flutter. I tried the firebase email and password authentication in a flutter project. but I face some problem that is when a user confirm their email it doesn't redirect to another new page. can anyone suggest me what to do?

```
 onPressed: () {
    if (emailAuthVerified.isUserVerified()) {
             EmailVerificationAlert();
                }
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.routeName);
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

After email verification you would have to `reload()` your user info/profile since `idTokenChanges()`, `userChanges()` & `authStateChanges()` won't be able to catch these changes.

Here's the reference: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage